# Extracting Outlook 2007 mail information to Excel from Excel - folder/subject

Tags: excel, outlook, text-extraction, vba

I want to extract the a subject of mails that have got a specific subject part to an Excel Worksheet (from Excel). So far, I am only able to extract the body, not the subject, and the part where the code searches for a subject is not finding anything. Could you please give any suggestion on how to find my emails (different getdefaultfolder?) and extract the subject?

Thanks in advance

```
Sub Work_with_Outlook()

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
Dim Fldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olMail As Variant
Dim sir() As String

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Test")
Set myTasks = Fldr.Items

Set olMail = myTasks.Find("[Subject] = ""*Test*"")
If Not (olMail Is Nothing) Then
sir = Split(olMail.Body, vbCrLf)
For i = 1 To UBound(sir)
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = sir(i)
Next i

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing..

```
sir = Split(olMail.Body, vbCrLf)
```

to

```
sir = Split(olMail.Subject, vbCrLf)
```

Comment: I´m sure that would work, thanks. But since no mail with the specified subject is found in the first place, I cannot try out your suggestion. So any advice on the search issue?

Comment: I think it could be about the wildcards used in 
    `Set olMail = myTasks.Find("[Subject] = ""*Test*"")`.